# ComboBox that display constant text in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I want to implement the second (Insert macro) solution in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/30139).

Is it possible to have a combo box that always display certain text (when collapsed)? It is bound to an ItemSource and user can expand the dropdown and select an item, but I want the text to always display "Insert macro" or something like that when it is collapsed. I don't want the custom text to be displayed as selection

Comment: Do you mean that in addition to the valid choices you want an extra one to be displayed by default?

Comment: No. What I mean is the text displayed in the combobox when it is collapsed should not be the selected item's text, but just a string. The string should not be displayed in the selection when the combobox is expanded.

Comment: use the onselectionchange event and override displayText value.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. 
First you have to define your own ToggleButtonStyle. The ControlTemplate holds a contentpresenter whose content is bound.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

You can add additional styling if you want to.

then you have to create a custom ComboBoxStyle. The easiest way to create it is to alter the default-template (in Blend rightclick on your ComboBox -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy).

The ContentPresenter within this template should have a Binding which looks like this:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
```

Simply delete this line and your ToggleButton should not get a new Content if a Item is selected.

Now you should be able to create your ComboBox with a fixed Content like this:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Text="Title">
```

Here are also some ControlTemplateExamples [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.